# replace character between patterns

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split a text document on two new-line characters:

```
# document example
field1: content asd..\n\nfield2: content qwe...\n\nfield3: content asfdqegt
```

but sometimes fields contain new-line characters within their content (see field2):

```
field1: content asd..\n\nfield2: content\n\nqwe...\n\nfield3: content asfdqegt
```

because of this, I can't use `\n\n` as separator

---

actual behavior:

```py
s = "field1: content asd..\n\nfield2: content\n\nqwe...\n\nfield3: content asfdqegt"
s.split("\n\n")
['field1: content asd..',
 'field2: content',
 'qwe...',
 'field3: content asfdqegt']
```

expected output *(need to replace `\n\n` between `field2:` and `field3:`, not all `\n\n` within document)*:

```py
s.split("\n\n")
['field1: content asd..', 'field2: contentqwe...', 'field3: content asfdqegt']
```

---

my attempt:

```py
import re
re.sub(r"(?<=field1: )(\n)(?<=field3: )", "", s) # does nothing
re.sub(r"\n", "", s) # replaces all \n, not just between field2 and field3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match from field to field and replace the newlines from the matches.

```
^field\d+:.*(?:\n(?!field\d+:).*)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `field\d+:.*` Match field followed by 1+ digits, `:` and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!field\d+:)` Assert that the string does not start with the field pattern
  - `.*` If the assertion is true, match the whole line
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat

As an example

```
import re

s = "field1: content asd..\n\nfield2: content\n\nqwe...\n\nfield3: content asfdqegt"
pattern = r"^field\d+:.*(?:\n(?!field\d+:).*)*"
res = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)]
print (res)
```

Output

```
['field1: content asd..', 'field2: contentqwe...', 'field3: content asfdqegt']
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBsqmt/1) and and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OwwxXA)

Comment: Just FYI: you do not need `\r?` as the `.` matches a CR symbol even without `re.S`/`re.DOTALL`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, I think somebody also told me that in the past..I just forgot about it. That is not always the case that the `.` matches a `\r` right? Let me read [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) again.

Comment: Yes, not always, in PCRE, it is controlled with `(*ANYCRLF)` and suchlike, in Java, there is `Pattern.UNIX_LINES` (the `(?d)` modifier).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
s = "field1: content asd..\n\nfield2: content\n\nqwe...\n\nfield3: content asfdqegt"
output = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in re.split(r"\n\n(?=\w+:)", s)]
print(output)
# => ['field1: content asd..', 'field2: contentqwe...', 'field3: content asfdqegt']
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lSnqV2). See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7GTJd5/1).

The `\n\n(?=\w+:)` pattern matches two LF chars that are immediately followed with one or more word chars and then a `:` char. After the string is split with this pattern, any LF char is removed from each chunk with `.replace('\n', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

If your field identifier is always "fieldX", you could use that to split as well:

```
>>> s.split('\n\nfield')
['field1: content asd..', '2: content\n\nqwe...', '3: content asfdqegt']
```